# Slider from the left side of screen to the right side of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

This is my first post so hello! :) 
I have a problem with coding my site!

May I show it on this picture:

[image]

I want to make a slider (with captions for each slide) which is aligned to the right edge of content div.wrap. But left side of it must by to the left side of the screen. It must change to the screen resolution (always to the right edge of the content div.wrap Something like this

[image]

Right edge of div.wrap must be a limit.

I have no idea how to do this. The slider must be a background fader? Or img fader?

Please help me or show me how to do this on similar example.

Comment: Maybe try putting this picture on an element with `position: absolute` inside the wrapper (`position: relative`). Then set `right: 0;` and let it overflow as much as it needs. Also you may need to set `body { overlow-x: hidden }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to @Itay's answer, here is a jsfiddle which might help you with the CSS for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/mmWq6/4/

I've used the example of a slider that is 500px by 200px. This is what I guessed would be a miniature version of the webpage I expect you're creating, if you scale the 'Result' window narrower and then wider again you'll see that I think the design works how you want it to.

This demo basically demonstrates Itay's comments, which were to have a wrapper (`#slider-wrapper`) which had the CSS `position: relative` and a div within that with the CSS:

```
#slider-wrapper-inner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Then within that are `.slide`s which are relatively positioned and `.caption`s within them that are positioned absolutely, as above (but with an extra line: `bottom: 0;`), so that they sit in the bottom right.